# Convert strings into table columns in biq query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to convert this table 
[image]

to something like this

[image]

the long string can be dynamic so it's important to me that it's not a fixed solution for these values specifically

Please help, i'm using big query

Comment: do you always have the same number of columns/

Comment: :o) quota from Q "the long string can be dynamic so it's important to me that it's not a fixed solution for these values specifically"

Comment: not possible ! you need to refactor you requirements / expectations. Usually if OP explains more about use case - we are able to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by using [SPLIT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#split) `SPLIT(value[, delimiter])` to convert your long string into separate key-value pairs in an array.
This will be sensitive to you having commas as part of your values.

`SPLIT(session_experiments, ',')`

Then you could either [FLATTEN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#flattening_arrays) that array or [access each element](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#accessing_array_elements), and then use some [REGEXs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) to separate the key and the value.

If you share more context on your restrictions and intended result I could try and put together a query for you that does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible what you want, however, there is a better practice for BigQuery.
You can use arrays of structs to store that information in a table.

Let's say you have a table like that
[image: Sample input]

You can use that sample query to understand how to use it.

```
with rawdata AS
(
  SELECT 1 as id, 'test1-val1,test2-val2,test3-val3' as experiments union all
  SELECT 1 as id, 'test1-val1,test3-val3,test5-val5' as experiments
)
select 
  id, 
  (select array_agg(struct(split(param, '-')[offset(0)] as experiment, split(param, '-')[offset(1)] as value)) from unnest(split(experiments)) as param ) as experiments
from rawdata
```

The output will look like that:
[image: Sample output]

After having that output, it's more convenient to manipulate the data